# IEEEtran template on Overleaf subsubsections

Tags: ieeetran

I want to change the subsubsection in the IEEEtran template that is in overleaf, the subsubsection is shown like this:

[image]

However I would like that the text in the subsubsection appears below the title and not by  the side with colon symbol, also if there is a way that there isn´t an indent in the subsubsection title.

I appreciate the help, the code of that page is here below.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  \graphicspath{{../Figuras/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.JPG,.jpeg,.png}

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}



\begin{document}


\title{\LARGE Title}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
}

\maketitle


\begin{IEEEkeywords}
 
\end{IEEEkeywords} 

\begin{abstract}
    
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Section} 

Something I should write in a section ...

\subsection{Subsection}

Something I should write in a subsection ...

\subsubsection{Subsubsections} 

Something I should write in a subsubsection ...

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,referencias}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[comsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
\graphicspath{{../Figuras/}}
% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
% every instance of \includegraphics
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.JPG,.jpeg,.png}

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\parindent}{1ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}%
    {0.7ex plus .5ex minus 0ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
    
    \title{\LARGE Title}
    \author{
        \IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
    }
    
    \maketitle
    
    
    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
        
    \end{IEEEkeywords} 
    
    \begin{abstract}
        
    \end{abstract}
    
    \IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
    
    \section{Section} 
    
    Something I should write in a section ...
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    Something I should write in a subsection ...
    
    \subsubsection{Subsubsections} 
    
    Something I should write in a subsubsection ...
    
%   \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%   \bibliography{IEEEabrv,referencias}
%   
\end{document}
```